# Query for many-to-many association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, has-and-belongs-to-many

There are 3 models in my project: Users, Games, GameVisits

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_visits
  has_many :games, through: :game_visits
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_visits
  has_many :users, through: :game_visits
end

class GameVisit < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :users_games
  enum status: [:visited, :not_visited, :unknown]
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game
end
```

My frontend is written in angularjs, so I want a function that for a list of games returns array of hashes each containing name of user and status or nil. Data is presented as table, cols - players, rows - games, cell - presence of player on game.
This is example of such function:

```
def team_json(game_ids = nil)
  game_ids ||= Game.pluck(:id)
  games = Game.find(game_ids)
  users = self.users
  result = []
  games.each do |game|
    record = {name: game.name, date: game.date }
    users_array = []
    users.each do |user|
      users_array << {
        name: user.name,
        status: user.game_visits.find_by_game_id(game.id)
      }
    end
    record[:users] = users_array
    result << record
  end
  result
end
```

Output:

[{:name=>"game 0", :date=>Fri, 19 Dec 2014 11:16:20 UTC +00:00, :users=>[{:name=>"Bob", :status=>nil}]},
 {:name=>"game 1", :date=>Sat, 20 Dec 2014 11:16:20 UTC +00:00, :users=>[{:name=>"Bob", :status=>nil}]},
 {:name=>"game 2", :date=>Fri, 19 Dec 2014 11:16:20 UTC +00:00, :users=>[{:name=>"Bob", :status=>nil}]}]

But this function produces tons of sql queries for GameVisits:

```
 (1.0ms)  SELECT "games"."id" FROM "games"
  Game Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "games".* FROM "games" WHERE "games"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101)
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."team_id" = $1  [["team_id", 1]]
  GameVisit Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users_games".* FROM "users_games" WHERE "users_games"."user_id" = $1 AND "users_games"."game_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 7], ["game_id", 1]]
  GameVisit Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users_games".* FROM "users_games" WHERE "users_games"."user_id" = $1 AND "users_games"."game_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 7], ["game_id", 2]]
  GameVisit Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users_games".* FROM "users_games" WHERE "users_games"."user_id" = $1 AND "users_games"."game_id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 7], ["game_id", 3]]
..............
```

How can I optimise it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `user.game_visits.find_by_game_id(game.id)` is what's firing all those queries. You can use eager-loading to get around this problem.

Change your assignment of `users` to the following:

```
users = self.users.includes(:game_visits)
```

Then change the value assignment of `status` in `users_array` to this:

```
status: user.game_visits.find{ |gv| gv.game_id == game.id }
```

The above line is using the enumerable's `find`, not ActiveRelation's. If you stick with `find_by_game_id` or some other `find` of AR, it'll still fire a query.

An additional optimization could be creating a hash for `game_visits` so that you can get around `find` altogether to do something like this:

```
user_game_visits_hash = \
  user.game_visits.each_with_object({}) do |gv, hash|
    hash[gv.game_id] = gv
  end

# more code here

status: user_game_visits_hash[game.id]
```

And a minor point: In case your `game_ids` in the method's arguments are nil, the first two lines of your method will unnecessarily fire two queries, because you `pluck` all ids from games just to fetch all games. You can change that to this:

```
games = game_ids ? Game.find(game_ids) : Game.all
```